# not being able to add dynamic expression to .json

Tags: azure-data-factory

do you see why I see the error when using the @guid() inside the below .json in the web activity of data factory

```
[
```

{
"id":@{guid()}
, "subject": "data/company"
, "topic": null, "eventType": "statusupdated"
, "eventTime": "2022-07-26T09:41:00.9584103Z", "data": { "firstName": "testname", "salary": "test" }, "dataVersion": "1.0", "metadataVersion": null
}
]

error when debug is run:

{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: b. Path '[0].id', line 2, position 5.'."}}

Answer (score 0):

- As the error message `The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: b. Path '[0].id', line 2, position 5` indicates, the issue is with the content.
- While parsing the JSON, it encountered an unexpected character. This is because of the value of the key `id` that is `@{guid()}`. You can validate the json using this [third-party validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) which indicates the same.
- The main issue is the incorrect usage of **String Interpolation (`@{...}`)**. This feature is used when we need to utilize pipeline expressions ***inside a string***.
- But here you have used it directly inside a json as a value for key (id). You can try correcting this by enclosing `@{guid()}` inside **Double quotes** ("") to make it **a valid JSON** (can be checked using the above third-party validator) as shown below:

```
[
{ "id": "@{guid()}" , "subject": "data/company" , "topic": null, "eventType": "statusupdated" , "eventTime": "2022-07-26T09:41:00.9584103Z", "data": { "firstName": "testname", "salary": "test" }, "dataVersion": "1.0", "metadataVersion": null } 
]
```